# How to prove that in a tree with $3$ leaves there's exactly one vertex of degree $3$?

Tags: proof-writing, trees

> Given a tree of $x$ vertices which has exactly $3$ leaves, prove that the tree has exactly one vertex of degree $3$.

I thought to prove this by contradiction: suppose there're at least $2$ vertices $v$ such that $\deg(v) = 3$. Then there're two cases:

1. The vertices don't share an edge. Then there're at least $4$ leaves in the tree.
2. The vertices share an edge like in the illustration below:

[image]

But then we can rearrange the tree to have $4$ vertices.

I realize that my second case is not strong because I need to prove that all trees where at least $2$ vertices have a degree of $3$ are isomorphic to the tree in my illustration, that's why I'm not sure how to finish the proof.

Comment: Your tree is binary isn't it?

Comment: @BillO'Haran no this is not given

Comment: @BillO'Haran No, it doesn't have to be.  Consider a tree with three leaves and one internal node connected to all three leaves.  That's a perfectly good tree for this theorem.

Comment: What relations do you know connecting the number of nodes, leaves, edges, and degrees of a tree?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi the statement should hold for **all** trees then. Or am I missing something in the question? Take the tree where the root has one child only and that child has 3 children. The statement does not hold.

Comment: @BillO'Haran You are thinking of rooted trees, but that's not what's assumed here.  In your example, there are four leaves.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi My mistake then. :)

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I know that $\sum_{v\in V} \deg(v)=2\cdot |E|$ and $E=|V|-1$ but I don't know relations between leaves and internal nodes

Comment: Try to prove that the tree cannot have vertices with degree 4 or higher. Then, with the above knowledge and the (now limited) set of potential deg($v$) values, maybe you can get a proof going.

Comment: @Ingix I think I got it: there're 3 nodes of degree 1 (the leaves), then other nodes can be only of degree 3 or 2 (we can rearrange node of degree 4 to be the root of the tree and then there're at least 4 leaves because all paths are disjoint). because of the handshaking lemma the sum of all degrees must be even, therefore at least one node must have degree 3. there can't be 2 nodes of degree 3 because then degrees sum is uneven and if we suppose that there're 3 nodes of degree 3 then even if all of them are adjacent there're at least 5 leaves which is a contradiction. Does this prove it?

Comment: You are on the right path, but your argument can be streamlined.  You know that a leaf's degree is $1$, and an internal node has degree at least $2$.  Let $s$ be the sum of the excess degrees (the sum of $\text{degree}(v)-2$ for each internal node $v$).  Use the handshaking lemma to compute $s$.  What's the meaning of $s=1$?